# JavaScript - Calculate from 2 dropdown menus the value between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, calculator

**I am trying to make a menu from scratch that allows you to calculate the price of a service, the price is equal to the first dropdown "until the second", like every single price between should be added. My code:

https://www.codecademy.com/JoaquimTD/codebits/N5vsNA

```js
var boosting_prices = new Array();
boosting_prices["b5"] = 5;
boosting_prices["b4"] = 5;
boosting_prices["b3"] = 5;
boosting_prices["b2"] = 7.5;
boosting_prices["b1"] = 10;
boosting_prices["s5"] = 10;
boosting_prices["s4"] = 10;
boosting_prices["s3"] = 10;
boosting_prices["s2"] = 12;
boosting_prices["s1"] = 12.5;
boosting_prices["g5"] = 12.5;
boosting_prices["g4"] = 12.5;
boosting_prices["g3"] = 12.5;
boosting_prices["g2"] = 15;
boosting_prices["g1"] = 17.5;
boosting_prices["p5"] = 20;
boosting_prices["p4"] = 20;
boosting_prices["p3"] = 20;
boosting_prices["p2"] = 22.5;
boosting_prices["p1"] = 25;
boosting_prices["d5"] = 30;
boosting_prices["d4"] = 40;
boosting_prices["d3"] = 55;
boosting_prices["d2"] = 80;
boosting_prices["d1"] = 160;

function getBoostPrice(){
    var yourLeague = document.getElementById("yourLeague").selectedIndex;
    var desiredLeague = document.getElementById("desiredLeague").selectedIndex;
    for ( var i = boosting_price[yourLeague].length; i =< boosting_price[desiredLeague].length; i++) {
        var totalPrice = 0;
        totalPrice += boosting_price[i];
    }
    var totalCalc = document.getElementById('totalCalc');
    totalCalc.innerHTML = totalPrice;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
 <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action=" " id="boostingForm">
 <div class="boostColumn" id="boostColumn">
  <label>Your League</label>
   <select id="yourLeague">
    <option value="Bronze V" id="b5" value="5">Bronze V</option>
    <option value="Bronze IV" id="b4" value="5">Bronze IV</option>
    <option value="Bronze III" id="b3" value="5">Bronze III</option>
    <option value="Bronze II" id="b2" value="7.5">Bronze II</option>
    <option value="Bronze I" id="b1" value="10">Bronze I</option>
    <option value="Silver V" id="s5" value="10">Silver V</option>
    <option value="Silver IV" id="s4" value="10">Silver IV</option>
    <option value="Silver III" id="s3" value="10">Silver III</option>
    <option value="Silver II" id="s2" value="12">>Silver II</option>
    <option value="Silver I" id="s1" value="12.5">Silver I</option>
    <option value="Gold V" id="g5" value="12.5">Gold V</option>
    <option value="Gold IV" id="g4" value="12.5">Gold IV</option>
    <option value="Gold III" id="g3" value="12.5">Gold III</option>
    <option value="Gold II" id="g2" value="15">Gold II</option>
    <option value="Gold I" id="g1" value="17.5">Gold I</option>
    <option value="Platinum V" id="p5" value="20">Platinum V</option>
    <option value="Platinum IV" id="p4" value="20">Platinum IV</option>
    <option value="Platinum III" id="p2" value="22.5">Platinum III</option>
    <option value="Platinum II" id="p1" value="25">Platinum II</option>
    <option value="Platinum I" id="p1" value="25">Platinum I</option>
    <option value="Diamond V" id="d5" value="30">Diamond V</option>
    <option value="Diamond IV" id="d4" value="40">Diamond IV</option>
    <option value="Diamond III" id="d3" value="55">Diamond III</option>
    <option value="Diamond II" id="d2" value="80">Diamond II</option>
    <option value="Diamond I" id="d1" value="160">Diamond I</option>
   </select>
 </div>
 <div class="boostColumn" id="boostColumn2">
  <label>Desired League</label>
   <select id="desiredLeague">
    <option value="Bronze V" id="b5" value="5">Bronze V</option>
    <option value="Bronze IV" id="b4" value="5">Bronze IV</option>
    <option value="Bronze III" id="b3" value="5">Bronze III</option>
    <option value="Bronze II" id="b2" value="7.5">Bronze II</option>
    <option value="Bronze I" id="b1" value="10">Bronze I</option>
    <option value="Silver V" id="s5" value="10">Silver V</option>
    <option value="Silver IV" id="s4" value="10">Silver IV</option>
    <option value="Silver III" id="s3" value="10">Silver III</option>
    <option value="Silver II" id="s2" value="12">>Silver II</option>
    <option value="Silver I" id="s1" value="12.5">Silver I</option>
    <option value="Gold V" id="g5" value="12.5">Gold V</option>
    <option value="Gold IV" id="g4" value="12.5">Gold IV</option>
    <option value="Gold III" id="g3" value="12.5">Gold III</option>
    <option value="Gold II" id="g2" value="15">Gold II</option>
    <option value="Gold I" id="g1" value="17.5">Gold I</option>
    <option value="Platinum V" id="p5" value="20">Platinum V</option>
    <option value="Platinum IV" id="p4" value="20">Platinum IV</option>
    <option value="Platinum III" id="p2" value="22.5">Platinum III</option>
    <option value="Platinum II" id="p1" value="25">Platinum II</option>
    <option value="Platinum I" id="p1" value="25">Platinum I</option>
    <option value="Diamond V" id="d5" value="30">Diamond V</option>
    <option value="Diamond IV" id="d4" value="40">Diamond IV</option>
    <option value="Diamond III" id="d3" value="55">Diamond III</option>
    <option value="Diamond II" id="d2" value="80">Diamond II</option>
    <option value="Diamond I" id="d1" value="160">Diamond I</option>
   </select>
 </div>
 <p id="totalCal">TOTAL</p>
 <input type="submit" class="orderButton" id="submitOrder" value="Order Now!" onclick="getBoostingPrice();">
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is to calculate the total price based on how many divisions the client wants. I tried to use a JavaScript Array for the prices, and use the id to identify them. Like I did in: boosting_prices[yourLeague.id].

I can use jQuery, JavaScript, PHP and HTML.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lots of bugs in your code, but I got your idea.

### HTML Bugs:

- you defined more than single value for each option and that's wrong
- you are using `<input type="submit">` instead of `<input type="button">` submit is used only when you want to post your data to the server
- you are calling undefined javascript funtions `getBoostingPrice` and js file has `getBoostPrice`

## Here is working code:

```js
function getBoostingPrice() {
  var yourLeague = document.getElementById("yourLeague").selectedIndex;
  var desiredLeague = document.getElementById("desiredLeague").selectedIndex;
  var options = document.getElementById("yourLeague").options;

  var totalPrice = 0;
  for (var i = yourLeague; i <= desiredLeague; i++) {
    totalPrice += parseInt(options[i].value);
  }
  var totalCalc = document.getElementById('totalCalc');
  totalCalc.innerHTML = totalPrice.toString();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action=" " id="boostingForm">
    <div class="boostColumn" id="boostColumn">
      <label>Your League</label>
      <select id="yourLeague">
        <option id="b5" value="5">Bronze V</option>
        <option id="b4" value="5">Bronze IV</option>
        <option id="b3" value="5">Bronze III</option>
        <option id="b2" value="7.5">Bronze II</option>
        <option id="b1" value="10">Bronze I</option>
        <option id="s5" value="10">Silver V</option>
        <option id="s4" value="10">Silver IV</option>
        <option id="s3" value="10">Silver III</option>
        <option id="s2" value="12">Silver II</option>
        <option id="s1" value="12.5">Silver I</option>
        <option id="g5" value="12.5">Gold V</option>
        <option id="g4" value="12.5">Gold IV</option>
        <option id="g3" value="12.5">Gold III</option>
        <option id="g2" value="15">Gold II</option>
        <option id="g1" value="17.5">Gold I</option>
        <option id="p5" value="20">Platinum V</option>
        <option id="p4" value="20">Platinum IV</option>
        <option id="p2" value="22.5">Platinum III</option>
        <option id="p1" value="25">Platinum II</option>
        <option id="p1" value="25">Platinum I</option>
        <option id="d5" value="30">Diamond V</option>
        <option id="d4" value="40">Diamond IV</option>
        <option id="d3" value="55">Diamond III</option>
        <option id="d2" value="80">Diamond II</option>
        <option id="d1" value="160">Diamond I</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="boostColumn" id="boostColumn2">
      <label>Desired League</label>
      <select id="desiredLeague">
        <option id="b5" value="5">Bronze V</option>
        <option id="b4" value="5">Bronze IV</option>
        <option id="b3" value="5">Bronze III</option>
        <option id="b2" value="7.5">Bronze II</option>
        <option id="b1" value="10">Bronze I</option>
        <option id="s5" value="10">Silver V</option>
        <option id="s4" value="10">Silver IV</option>
        <option id="s3" value="10">Silver III</option>
        <option id="s2" value="12">Silver II</option>
        <option id="s1" value="12.5">Silver I</option>
        <option id="g5" value="12.5">Gold V</option>
        <option id="g4" value="12.5">Gold IV</option>
        <option id="g3" value="12.5">Gold III</option>
        <option id="g2" value="15">Gold II</option>
        <option id="g1" value="17.5">Gold I</option>
        <option id="p5" value="20">Platinum V</option>
        <option id="p4" value="20">Platinum IV</option>
        <option id="p2" value="22.5">Platinum III</option>
        <option id="p1" value="25">Platinum II</option>
        <option id="p1" value="25">Platinum I</option>
        <option id="d5" value="30">Diamond V</option>
        <option id="d4" value="40">Diamond IV</option>
        <option id="d3" value="55">Diamond III</option>
        <option id="d2" value="80">Diamond II</option>
        <option id="d1" value="160">Diamond I</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    TOTAL: <span id="totalCalc"></span>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" class="orderButton" id="submitOrder" value="Order Now!" onclick="getBoostingPrice();">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So as I understood you used the HTML options as the array itself? Like the price was the same of the two dropdown menus so it made it easier. You also made the value always an integer? Can I ask why? I will be improving my code to include images depending on the selectedIndex as well as a cooler style in CSS, I am working in a website that I host to improve my coding skills. The idea is to implement also a payment system later, should I learn WePay API or any comments about how to code it? I have beginner knowledge in PHP, HTML, JS, jQ, CSS and Py.

Comment: I've to convert the value to integer to be able to sum them `totalPrice += parseInt(options[i].value);` if I dont, the total price will concatenate the number together as string